# TABLOCK vs TABLOCKX

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What is the difference between `TABLOCK` and `TABLOCKX`?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx states that `TABLOCK` is a shared lock while `TABLOCKX` is an exclusive lock. Is the first maybe only an index lock of sorts? And what is the concept of sharing a lock?

Comment: It states that `TABLOCK` is a *shared* lock allowing multiple clients to concurrently load data into the table. An exclusive lock does not.

Comment: @Lieven With tablocks the mutual exclusitivity is excluded from the lock in which the datatable is consived in a reserved page memory cycle.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Big difference, `TABLOCK` will try to grab "shared" locks, and `TABLOCKX` exclusive locks.

If you are in a transaction and you grab an exclusive lock on a table, EG:

`SELECT 1 FROM TABLE WITH (TABLOCKX)`

No other processes will be able to grab **any** locks on the table, meaning **all** queries attempting to talk to the table will be blocked until the transaction commits.

`TABLOCK` only grabs a shared lock, shared locks are released after a statement is executed if your transaction isolation is `READ COMMITTED` (default). If your isolation level [is higher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql), for example: `SERIALIZABLE`, shared locks are held until the end of a transaction.

---

Shared locks are, hmmm, shared. Meaning 2 transactions can both read data from the table at the same time if they both hold a S or IS lock on the table (via `TABLOCK`). However, if `transaction A` holds a shared lock on a table, `transaction B` will not be able to grab an exclusive lock until all shared locks are released. Read about which locks are compatible with which [at msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide#lock_compatibility).

---

Both hints cause the db to bypass taking more granular locks (like row or page level locks). In principle, more granular locks allow you better concurrency. So for example, one transaction could be updating row 100 in your table and another row 1000, *at the same time* from two transactions (it gets tricky with page locks, but lets skip that).

In general granular locks is what you want, but sometimes you may want to reduce db concurrency to increase performance of a particular operation and eliminate the chance of deadlocks.

In general you would not use `TABLOCK` or `TABLOCKX` unless you absolutely needed it for some edge case.

Comment: One of those edge cases is, for instance, a situation where you initially create the table and fill it with data with, say, `INSERT INTO`. In such situations an exclusive lock can give you a big performance gain.

Comment: meaning **all** queries attempting to **talk** to the table will be blocked until the transaction commits. 

This isn't true. You can still do reads with the NOLOCK or TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working on sql server 2016 ?

Answer (score 6):

Quite an old [article on mssqlcity](http://www.mssqlcity.com/Articles/Adm/SQL70Locks.htm) attempts to explain the types of locks:

> Shared locks are used for operations that do not change or update data, such as a SELECT statement.
>
> Update locks are used when SQL Server intends to modify a page, and later promotes the update page lock to an exclusive page lock before actually making the changes.
>
> Exclusive locks are used for the data modification operations, such as UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE.

What it doesn't discuss are Intent (which basically is a modifier for these lock types). Intent (Shared/Exclusive) locks are locks held at a higher level than the real lock. So, for instance, if your transaction has an X lock on a row, it will also have an IX lock at the table level (which stops other transactions from attempting to obtain an incompatible lock at a higher level on the table (e.g. a schema modification lock) until your transaction completes or rolls back).

---

The concept of "sharing" a lock is quite straightforward - multiple transactions can have a Shared lock for the same resource, whereas only a single transaction may have an Exclusive lock, and an Exclusive lock precludes any transaction from obtaining or holding a Shared lock.

Comment: Is there a difference in how long the locks are held? TABLOCK is held until the end-of-statement. If HOLDLOCK is also specified, the shared table lock is held until the end of the transaction. But what about TABLOCKX

Comment: @Carlo - Exclusive locks are always held until the end of the transaction.

Comment: @Carlo, all shared locks are released at the end of a statement in a read committed transaction, if you want to hold the locks you need hints or a higher isolation level. `tablockx` will grab an X lock.

Answer (score 5):

This is more of an example where TABLOCK did not work for me and TABLOCKX did.

I have 2 sessions, that both use the default (READ COMMITTED) isolation level:

Session 1 is an explicit transaction that will copy data from a linked server to a set of tables in a database, and takes a few seconds to run. [Example, it deletes Questions]
Session 2 is an insert statement, that simply inserts rows into a table that Session 1 doesn't make changes to. [Example, it inserts Answers].

(In practice there are multiple sessions inserting multiple records into the table, simultaneously, while Session 1 is running its transaction).

Session 1 has to query the table Session 2 inserts into because it can't delete records that depend on entries that were added by Session 2. [Example: Delete questions that have not been answered].

So, while Session 1 is executing and Session 2 tries to insert, Session 2 loses in a deadlock every time.

So, a delete statement in Session 1 might look something like this:
DELETE tblA FROM tblQ LEFT JOIN tblX on ...
LEFT JOIN tblA a ON tblQ.Qid = tblA.Qid
WHERE ... a.QId IS NULL and ...

The deadlock seems to be caused from contention between querying tblA while Session 2, [3, 4, 5, ..., n] try to insert into tblA.

In my case I could change the isolation level of Session 1's transaction to be SERIALIZABLE.  When I did this: The transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions.

So, I could follow instructions in the accepted answer here to get around it: [The transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130767/the-transaction-manager-has-disabled-its-support-for-remote-network-transactions)

But a) I wasn't comfortable with changing the isolation level to SERIALIZABLE in the first place- supposedly it degrades performance and may have other consequences I haven't considered, b) didn't understand why doing this suddenly caused the transaction to have a problem working across linked servers, and c) don't know what possible holes I might be opening up by enabling network access.

There seemed to be just 6 queries within a very large transaction that are causing the trouble.

So, I read about TABLOCK and TabLOCKX.

I wasn't crystal clear on the differences, and didn't know if either would work.  But it seemed like it would.  First I tried TABLOCK and it didn't seem to make any difference. The competing sessions generated the same deadlocks.  Then I tried TABLOCKX, and no more deadlocks.

So, in six places, all I needed to do was add a WITH (TABLOCKX).

So, a delete statement in Session 1 might look something like this:
DELETE tblA FROM tblQ q LEFT JOIN tblX x on ...
LEFT JOIN tblA a WITH (TABLOCKX) ON tblQ.Qid = tblA.Qid
WHERE ... a.QId IS NULL and ...

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Thanks for posting your first answer. I think this answer would be more useful to others though if you removed the personal references and kept to the basic facts. Keep up the good work!