# TABLOCK And TABLOCKX definition example

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Can someone explain TABLOCKX and TABLOCK keyword and show examples anout this keyword.

What is the functions of these 2 words in queries?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [TABLOCK vs TABLOCKX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102152/tablock-vs-tablockx)

Comment: Homework question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102152/tablock-vs-tablockx

Answer (score 3):

i use the "WITH (TABLOCK)" statement in an insert into an empty clustered table to minimally log the transaction:

```
INSERT INTO myTable WITH (TABLOCK)
(Column1, Column2...)
SELECT X, Y from Z
```

Answer (score 0):

`TABLOCK` obtains a shared lock, and `TABLOCKX` obtains an exclusive lock.

Here's an example of both:

```
select *
from yourtableSharedLock
with (tablock)

select *
from yourtableExclusiveLock
with (tablockx)
```