# Lock a SQL server Table for a given time and check if it is locked

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, table-lock

I want to lock a table for a given amount of time in SQL Server . I am using C# at code level. How can I achieve it, I also need to verify that the table is locked or not. I do not have much knowledge of locking tables in SQL Server. I want to achieve it using entity framework. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25273157/t-sql-lock-a-table-manually-for-some-minutes

Comment: It cannot be done with pure entity-framework.  You'll **have** to use dao.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try as shown below.

```
using (var context = new YourContext())
    {
     using (var dbContextTransaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
     {
       //Lock the table during this transaction
       context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SELECT 1 FROM YourTable WITH (TABLOCKX)
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:03:00'");

            //your work here

            dbContextTransaction.Commit();
      }
}
```

**Note :**  The table lock will be released after it exits the `BeginTransaction` block

Comment: a small edit. I should be `dbContextTransaction.Commit()` instead of `scope.Commit()` and Table in SQL command to be replaced by actual Table name