# SELECT statement is not blocked by an existing exclusive table lock

Tags: sql-server

For testing, I am trying to simulate a condition in which a query from our web application to our SQL Server backend would timeout. The web application is configured so this happens if the query runs longer than 30 seconds. I felt the easiest way to do this would be to take and hold an exclusive lock on the the table that the web application wants to query. As I understand it, an exclusive lock should prevent any additional locks (even the shared locks taken by a SELECT statement).

I used the following methodology:

**CREATE A LONG-HELD LOCK**

Open a first query window in SSMS and run

```
BEGIN TRAN; 
    SELECT * FROM MyTable WITH (TABLOCKX); 
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:02:00';
ROLLBACK;
```

(see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25274225/2824445 )

**CONFIRM THE LOCK**

I can `EXEC sp_lock` and see results with ObjId matching MyTable, Type of `TAB`, Mode of `X`

**TRY TO GET BLOCKED BY THE LOCK**

Open a second query window in SSMS and run `SELECT * FROM MyTable`

I would expect this to sit and wait, not returning any results until after the lock is released by the first query. Instead, the second query returns with full results immediately.

**STUFF I TRIED**

- In the second query window, if I `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE`, then the second query waits until the first completes as expected. However, the point is to simulate a timeout in our web application, and I do not have any easy way to alter the transaction isolation level of the web application's connections away from the default of `READ COMMITTED`.
- In the first window, I tried modifying the table's values inside the transaction. In this case, when the second query returns immediately, the values it shows are the unmodified values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. We had READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT turned on, which is how the second query was able to return the previous, unmodified values in part 2 of "Stuff I tried". I was able to determine this with `SELECT is_read_committed_snapshot_on FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'MyDatabase'`. Once it was turned off with `ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF`, I began to see the expected behavior in which the second query would wait for the first to complete.