# SQL Server lock database while stoting incoming requests in a queue

Tags: sql-server, locking

Is there a way to lock an entire database from writing but at the same time storing the incoming requests in a queue or in memory until the lock is released?

edit 1:
I'm looking for something similar to MySQL

'FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK' and 'UNLOCK TABLES'

Thanks

Comment: Locking an entire database is a very bad idea.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for, but this might help: http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/

Comment: Offtopic. Not really a programming question. Try the DBA site.

Comment: I know it's a bad idea but this is one of my requirenments :(

Comment: SQL Server does have lock hints.  Just google it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add table level lock hints with (tablock) or with (tablockx) depending if you need shared or exclusive lock -- that's of course per table.

[TABLOCK vs TABLOCKX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102152/tablock-vs-tablockx)