# SQL Server. How to apply an exclusive lock on a table while an insert is being made?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to apply an exclusive lock on a table while an insert is being made? In my case two different threads are inserting values into same table and they cannot see other transaction's data being inserted.

I want that while one transaction is inserting the rows, other transaction waits till first transaction has finished inserting the values.

Piece of SQL Trigger:-

```
BEGIN
    insert into A(SETID,ACCTID,UPDATEDTM)
    select @setid, l.acctid, getdate() 
    from AccountTable l where --(conditions for where clause)
```

I want to lock table `A` for insert operations being done.

Comment: Take a look at TABLOCK or TABLOCKX

Comment: @RichBenner can you please provide syntax for it. I tried searching over google but could not get something fruitful.

Comment: I've put the code into an answer below, tablockx is classed as a table hint. I've added further reading too.

Answer (score 3):

Give TABLOCKX a go this will give you exclusive locks on the data;

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO A WITH (TABLOCKX) (SETID,ACCTID,UPDATEDTM) 
SELECT @setid, l.acctid, getdate() 
FROM AccountTable l WHERE (conditions for where clause)
```

Further reading;

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187373.aspx

[TABLOCK vs TABLOCKX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102152/tablock-vs-tablockx)

Comment: The table hint goes after the table name, not the column specification.

Comment: @RichBenner thanks for your help. It made my day, as I was stuck with an issue since 5 days.