How to prevent read queries hitting incrementally loaded tables during the load?
I'm incrementally loading 6 tables inside of a SQL transaction.
Each table takes about one minute. The problem I'm faced with is that - while the 1st table is being loaded, the reports that hit the 2nd table onwards aren't blocked. Thus they fetch inconsistent data.
I want to make it such that while the etl load is in progress, none of the 6 tables must be readable. Evidently transactions like how I'm using it isn't the solution.
What can I do to handle this.

You need to add specifics - actual tables, what they contain, how they're modified, how much data there is. We can't guess what you're doing. Reporting databases are built so they don't have such issues.  The fact table in a star schema for example is append-only. Changes to dimension tables are made before loading the fact table. The data is prepared in staging tables before it's sent to the fact tables. As for reports, they're valid at the moment of execution.

SQL Server allows instantaneous partition switching between matching tables too. This means you can prepare the data in a staging table and then swap the staging and final tables or swap specific partitions between them. This is essentially a metadata operation that changes what table the data pages belong to. For dimension/lookup tables, you can prepare the entire new table on the side, then swap it with the target table

The key is the transaction that will include all changes to the tables. Whether and how you block other users depends on the isolation levels and approach (whether you do it on target or stageing tables).
Read about updlock, but there's a good chance you need to do SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TN WITH (TABLOCKX, HOLDLOCK) at the beginning of the transaction for each table you want to deny users access to. Only then can you start loading them.
The second option is to enable the READ COMMITED SNAPSHOT isolation level.
That's pretty much it if I understood the context correctly.
edit1: M$ decided that each SELECT or INSERT (DML) command is a small transaction that "guarantees" certain data properties such as consistency after its completion. For example, the consistency of the index on table X with table X. Any other relationship between data such as yours must be "guaranteed" by your code.
The simplest solutions from my experience, if such problems start to occur, are:

Disable users' access to the database until all ETLs are complete.

Instruct users that they must verify the business consistency of the data themselves.


Any other solution required me to make a huge commitment to learning how isolation levels and transactions work in available database solutions and this knowledge cannot be transferred to business users.
edit2:
3. Another idea from data warehouse is to load everything or current partitions on the side and switch in one "transaction" - a bit more juggling of structures (watch out for Sch-M/S).
edit3:
Is it me or is the environment currently poisonous? every -1 for such questions is +1 NOLOCK in your database!

Read commited will give another problem that is once done loading 1, 2 tables... Users will see data from 1, 2 but inconsistent data from 3, 4...

But surely you hold transaction over the whole load? If not, then you got bigger problems

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69914220/difference-between-tablockx-and-tablockx-holdlock#:~:text=By%20specifying%20TABLOCK%2C%20the%20shared,is%20taken%20on%20the%20table. Says that tablock by itself is enough?

I'll learn more about read commited snapshot...

Please explain the actual scenario. ETL and data warehousing is more than just transactions. Blocking report users is definitely not a good idea and simply impractical for large data warehouses.

ETLs and DWs are beautiful ideals, but reality is dirty. If OP starts getting into BI he probably has a 90% chance of losing a lot of $$$.

@SKK - can you tell me how snapshot isolation by itself helps to solve this problem. So I still need to use tablock and holdlock? For example say load is ongoing on table 3. When my reports read table 1, 2, 3 it will read original versions. But for table 5, 6 reporting queries will read current version.i want it such that all 6 tabels should be either before the transaction starts or after commit.

You understand correctly that you have to start a transaction anyway - the database will never guess how many tables you want to update. The advantage of a snapshot is that you do not block readings and you do not have to do separate select with tablock. After each update of subsequent tables, users will still read the version of data from the moment you did BEGIN TRANSACTION.

In relation to SERIALIZABLE you will also have less chance of deadlock if in the meantime another process wants to load exactly the same data. If you have time you can test your process to see if SERIALIZABLE + transaction will not be a sufficient solution in your case.
